# Find a cubed function knowing the maximum and the point of inflection?

Tags: functions

Is it possible to find the function of a cubed line if we know its maximum and its point of inflection?

if yes, can some one explain me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's a "cubed line"?

Comment: And if you mean "cubing function", what do you mean by "maximum"?

Comment: You have had two requests for clarification, and one answer, and we've not heard anything back from you - are you still there?

Comment: graphtheory92: remember to upvote, and/or accept answers you find to be helpful. You can accept one answer per question, but you can upvote any/all answers that are correct, that help, etc. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that there's an equation $y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are unknowns to be found - if that's not what you have in mind, please clarify.

I also assume you know there is a local maximum at $(r,s)$, and a point of inflection at $(u,v)$.

So what you know is $y(r)=s$, $y'(r)=0$, $y(u)=v$, and $y''(u)=0$. Well, that's four linear equations in four unknowns, I'm sure you can handle that.

EDIT: As J.M. notes in the comments, this is an example of [Hermite interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation).

Comment: This is in fact a Hermite interpolation problem...